# Should I use xcassets or just change the size of one image to develop on multiple devices in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uicollectionview, xcasset

I want to show a placeholder image on my `UICollectionView` until the cell fetches an image from my server. However, I wonder whether I should prepare three different images in advance for the case 1x, 2x, and 3x in `Images.xcassests`,  or just prepare one SVG file and manipulate its size once the image is loaded within code.

Specifically, if you take the first approach your procedure is something like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImageInXcassets")) // frame is set to the size of the image automatically
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

And this is the second approach:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage"))
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 128, 128) // alter the frame depending on the size of the device
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

So here is my question:

- Is there any difference at the output of the image displayed?
- If you use SVG file you don't need to worry about seeing the dirty image even after expanding the size, right?
- Which is the better in performance or a recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Image assets for image loading for various device is more performance effective and faster and is encouraged by apple themselves.

Comment: Any link to "is encouraged by apple themselves"?

Comment: You can check out this [blog](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/31369/unleash-your-inner-app-developer-managing-images-xcode-5-asset-catalogs)

Comment: Thanks. I want to know more about the improved performance, though.